# Bundled JS libraries e.g. angular, jQuery, lodash after eval throws "require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, gruntjs, fetch

I'm bundling diffrent JS libraries using grunt-contrib-concat as follows:

```
dist7: {
    src: [
        'lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'lib/ng1.6/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
        'lib/ng1.6/angular-aria/angular-aria.js',
        'lib/ng1.6/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
        'lib/api-check/dist/api-check.js',
        'lib/angular-formly/dist/formly.js',
        'lib/ng1.6/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
        'lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        'lib/lodash/lodash.js',
        'lib/angularjs-toaster/toaster.js',
        'lib/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js',
        'lib/eventie/eventie.js',
        'lib/wolfy87-eventemitter/EventEmitter.js',
        'lib/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.js',
        'lib/desandro-matches-selector/matches-selector.js',
        'lib/doc-ready/doc-ready.js',
        'lib/fizzy-ui-utils/utils.js',
        'lib/desandro-get-style-property/get-style-property.js',
        'lib/get-size/get-size.js',
        'lib/outlayer/item.js',
        'lib/outlayer/outlayer.js',
        'lib/masonry-layout/masonry.js'],
    dest: 'dist/js/my-dependencies.js'
}
```

When I'm adding `dist/js/my-dependencies.js` in script tag it works.

But when I'm doing a fetch request then I do eval like following:

```
fetch('dist/js/my-dependencies.js', {method: 'GET'})
    .then(response => response.text()))).then(scr => {
        eval(scr)
    });
```

It thoows folowing error:

```
Err in evaling:  /cuicui/scripts/js/my-dependencies.js  With err: 
 ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at installedModules (eval at <anonymous> (cd.component.js:12), <anonymous>:1:93)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (cd.component.js:12), <anonymous>:1:554)
    at cd.component.js:12
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at cd.component.js:12
    at <anonymous>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem:
One of your dependancies has a `require('someLib')` at the top(prob) of the file.

How to find:
go through each libary and do a search for the keyword `require`

Why does eval fail?
`eval()` is on the window not in node.  And therefore, it doesn't know how to handle that keyword.  I would suggest finding pre-minfied versions of all your libraries and not using the library source.

Comment: require is being used by some libraries like angular internally but I'm not sure where they r resolving it from?